# Grub and Logical Volume Management

Tags: grub, lvm

I've not been able to find any relevant information in the Arch Wiki about using LVM with Grub as the bootloader (BIOS).

Let's say I've created the volume group 'volgroup00' using partitions spanning three devices, e.g.:

```
vgcreate volgroup00 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdc1
```

One of the LV's created from this group is used as the root partition.

However, where wishing to install grub, the device must be specified. If I wanted to install grub to the same device as root, then since the LV used for root was created from a VG consisting of three devices (i.e. sda, sdb, and sdc), how would I know which device to pick?

```
# grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck /dev/sda
# grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck /dev/sdb
# grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck /dev/sdc
```

Comment: You pick the logical volume corresponding to root. Probably something that looks like `dev/volgroup00/root` I'm not sure I understand the question. Please include the output of `lvs` in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You want to install GRUB on whichever disk your motherboard (BIOS/UEFI) is configured to boot to. That's probably the first hard drive, `/dev/sda`.

Often the BIOS will just be configured to boot to "hard drives," and will boot to the first *bootable* disk. In that case, as long as the other two disks aren't bootable, it wouldn't matter on which disk you installed GRUB, but boot would be slightly faster with it on the first disk because the system's search would conclude more quickly.

GRUB itself does not have to be on the same disk as the boot data. In fact, if you were using three-disk RAID, you would want to install GRUB on all three disks so you could still boot in the event of a drive failure.